# How to use same App.config for multiple clients

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, app-config

I am a newbie at .NET and I need help.

1) There is possible to have an App.config file at network folder and use those setting for multiple clients? if yes, how can I do that?

2) If I will make a change in this App.config, it will effect in real-time?

The idea is that I want to create one configuration file that will affect all clients without having to update app.config in each client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider to make symbolic link to your network path

```
 mklink /H "C:\myApp\app.config" "\\server\shared_app\app.config"
```

ake sure that users have only  read permission to file.

Comment: To refresh in run-time, I used this:
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");